# Gparted complains about lack of space to create a partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I just installed Ubuntu 17 and removed my Windows 10 entirely.

I didn't have important data so I chose to erase all my data.

Now I'm facing a problem in creating a partition. Gparted keeps telling me I only have 192MB free:

[image: gparted detailes]

[image: 192 mb free only !!]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: I've already seen this thread :) it's different. I explained above.

Comment: Have you considered this answer in particular: https://askubuntu.com/a/237453/480481
Looks like your root partition has taken up the whole drive (except the minimal 192GB free space).

Comment: Yea i tried thia method particularly, and didn't work it's 192 MB not GB. That's why it's driving me crazy

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to achieve? You set up Ubuntu to use logical volumes instead of partitions which can certainly be managed and resized but not with GParted.

Comment: You already have a partition created, and mounted.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create/modify LVM volumes using the CLI, or you could install a GUI like `system-config-lvm`.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
```

Then type `lvm` into the Unity dashboard search box to start this app.

## Do backups of important files before trying to modify LVM volumes/partitions.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm for basic help. You can also search https://help.ubuntu.com for "system-config-lvm" and find a lot more detailed help.